# Is a single rejection final?

Tags: support, documentation

My [proposed improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/13523) was rejected by a single user.  Can any single user veto any proposed change?

Comment: At the moment it needs 2 approvals or one reject. But you can try to improve your draft: http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes